# Error no pg_hba.conf entry for host when using PG client, but not when connecting with psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-promise

I'm pointing my application from one PG cluster to another (changing the team that manages the PG cluster), and I'm getting connection errors when trying to connect with a [language binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding) for [javascript](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
no pg_hba.conf entry for host xxx.x.x.x, user "blah", database "blah", SSL off
```

I'm led to believe that this is a pg_hba.conf configuration error, but I can connect to the cluster with `psql`, from the same machine, with the same credentials.

- psql: 9.5.7,
- PG cluster 10.5
- Client: pg-promise 9.3.3

How can this be possible? Is this still definitely an issue with how pg_hba.conf is set up or is there something wrong with how I configured my client? This is not the first time I've used it, I've been connecting to a PG cluster v. 9.5.7 for the last couple of years.

Comment: Could you explain how exactly you are transferring data from one cluster to another, and what a "language binding" is? Have you looked in the log file of the PostgreSQL server for more information about the failed connection attempt?

Comment: Is your application running in a docker container with a different IP address by chance?

Comment: It is in a docker container, but I can execute psql from within the container and connect successfully. I'm suspecting the SSL part, that's one of the differences in the new cluster. Does the psql client automatically accept the certs presented?

Comment: Ok, I just figured out that it was actually the SSL on the new cluster. I configured the language binding to use SSL and I can connect now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the new cluster is using SSL for the connection. When I connected to the old cluster, there was no SSL, so the connection worked with my current config, but when switching to the new cluster I had to specify that SSL was being used.

https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Connection-Syntax